# В чём отличие flash drive от thumb drive для функции GetDriveType?

Tags: c++, winapi

Разбираюсь с WinAPI-функцией `GetDriveType`. Она возвращает тип диска. Для съёмных дисков функция должна вернуть **DRIVE_REMOVABLE**. Процитирую описание с **msdn**:

> The drive has removable media; for example, a floppy drive, thumb
>   drive, or flash card reader.

Насколько я понимаю, *thumb drive* - это обычная флешка.
Но в то же время, для устройства с английским названием *flash drive* функция GetDriveType должна вернуть **DRIVE_FIXED**. Снова процитирую **msdn**:

> The drive has fixed media; for example, a hard disk drive or flash
>   drive.

Может быть Microsoft имела ввиду *SSD*, ведь в них почти всегда используется флеш-память. Но я никогда не слышал, чтобы *SSD* называли *flash drive*. А вот флешки так называют очень часто. Хотелось бы узнать, что Microsoft понимают под термином *flash drive*.

Comment: `flash card reader` - читайте все три слова. Это кардридер для чтения карт памяти

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ,  это Вам следует читать повнимательнее. Я спрашивал про устройство под названием flash drive и его отличия от thumb drive. Про устройство flash card reader у меня нет никаких вопросов)

Comment: Рассуждая чисто логически. Похоже, что термином `DRIVE_FIXED` обозначают устройства со встроенным контроллером, который "экранирует" непосредственно media (т.е. среду, которая хранит данные) от контроллера, с которым напрямую работает драйвер (на нижнем уровне).

Comment: @avp , согласен, очень на это похоже.

Answer (score 1):

Для функции GetDriveType в данном случае важно как диск подключен, а не что у него внутри. Внешний HDD с блинами - тоже DRIVE_REMOVABLE, поскольку легко может быть отключен.

Comment: У меня нет внешнего диска, чтобы проверить самому, но вся найденная в интернете документация и форумы говорят, что внешний HDD определяется как DRIVE_FIXED. К тому же не зря, наверное, Microsoft для определения того, что диск подключен по USB рекомендует использовать SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty с параметром SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY?

Comment: И какая же официальная документация говорит, что HDD по USB-шине - DRIVE_FIXED?

Comment: Ну так, чтобы прямым текстом было написано: "подключенный по usb hdd даст DRIVE FIXED", конечно в документации нет. Но видел на многих форумах пока искал про flash drive. Конечно, не могу утверждать, что это 100% правда поскольку сам не пробовал.

Comment: Но если GetDriveType сама определяет все устройства на USB-шине как DRIVE_REMOVABLE, то зачем же в офф. документации вот эта фраза: "To determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, call SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty and specify the SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY property."?

Comment: "на многих форумах" и "официальная документация" так же соотносятся, как слово из трех букв на сарае и дрова внутри него. Кроме USB я могу рассказать про: FireWire, E-SATA и прочие способы подключения съемных устройств.

Comment: Не то, чтобы я Вам не верил, но вот ряд ссылок:http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=43396 http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?322540-USB-Hard-Disk-and-GetDriveType-API http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-basic/thread744327.html https://forum.shelek.ru/index.php?debug;/topic,2170.0.html?prev_next=next. Зачем такому количеству разных людей врать? Я конечно допускаю, что у них были какие-то неправильные диски или левые драйвера. Но не надо такой категоричности)

Comment: Весьма возможно, что Windows определяет тип диска не по шине, а каким-то другим образом. Например, читает инфу из первого сектора диска. Может я и не прав. Буду очень благодарен, если покажете место в документации, где указано обратное)

Comment: Если бы вы читали первый сектор диска, то знали бы, что такой информации там не содержится и содержаться не должно.

Comment: Ок, в этом я и правда не разбираюсь. Информация может быть вшита в другом месте на устройстве или в драйвере. Неважно. Я всего лишь делаю логический вывод - если бывают проблемы с определением типа устройства, то значит этот самый тип определяется не по шине. К тому же остаётся мой изначальный вопрос - что такое flash drive, который возвращает DRIVE_FIXED. Если Ваша точка зрения правильная, то это Microsoft SSD с флеш-памятью внутри так обозвала. В принципе это возможно, хотя и странно)